# regarding multiple choice field

Tags: python, django

I have many objects in categories. like

```
 English
 etc
 French
```

I tried to display that categories into `multiplechocieField`. So I'm using following code. But its just display last object like. 
`French`

Here is my forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
categories = Category.objects.all()
for c in  categories:
    CHOICES = ((c.id,c.name),)

answers = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHOICES)
```

Will you please help me? thank you

UPDATE : I tried Chewie solution. But Now i'm getting 
`TemplateSyntaxError at /users/profile/
Caught ValueError while rendering: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning (not appending) a new value to `CHOICES` in every iteration of the `for` loop. It should be something like:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
categories = Category.objects.all()
CHOICES = []
for c in  categories:
    CHOICES.append((c.id, c.name))

answers = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHOICES)
```

And anyway, perhaps you should be using a proper `ForeignKey` for that field.

> But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you're
>   probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey.
>   choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: My (our) mistake. I was appending a tuple of tuples, instead of a tuple. Already fixed it, you just have to remove a couple of parenthesis.